# Can't open new activity from recycleview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm searching how to open new cardview from my recycleview to see de detail of my prospect.

5 files is used to do the job.
The problem is : why went i press one of this card any activity is lunched ?

```html
package ml2v.demenagement.all.android.ui.interfaces

import ProspectAdminAdapter
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Switch
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.SlideInUpAnimator
import ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model.CardClickListener
import ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model.PROSPECT_ID_EXTRA
import ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model.Prospect
import ml2v.demenagement.app.android.R
import java.util.Objects

class AdminProspects() : ComponentActivity(), CardClickListener {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private val prospectList = mutableListOf<Prospect>()
    private var filteredList = mutableListOf<Prospect>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_prospects)
        actionBar?.hide()

        recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.prospects_views)
        val adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(prospectList)
        adapter.setCardClickListener(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter



        val switchWaiting: Switch = findViewById(R.id.waiting)
        val switchInProgress: Switch = findViewById(R.id.in_progress)
        val switchValidate: Switch = findViewById(R.id.validate)
        val switchPro: Switch = findViewById(R.id.switch_pro)
        val switchPerso: Switch = findViewById(R.id.switch_perso)

        var isWaitingSelected = false
        var isInProgressSelected = false
        var isValidatedSelected = false

        // BDD
        val db = Firebase.firestore
        val prospectsCollection = db.collection("demenagement")
        recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.prospects_views)

        prospectsCollection.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                val prospect = document.data
                // Traitez les données du prospect ici
                val categorie = prospect["categorie"] as String
                val email = prospect["mail"] as String
                val nom = prospect["nom"] as String
                val siret = prospect["siret"] as String
                val tel = prospect["tel"] as String
                val type = prospect["type"] as String
                val status = prospect["status"] as String
                val usersuid = prospect["users"] as String

                //Récupération du nom de l'utilisateur en fonction de son uid
                val usersCollection = db.collection("users")

                usersCollection.document(usersuid).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                    val userName = document.getString("nom").toString()
                    val newProspect = Prospect(categorie, email, nom, siret, tel, type, userName, status)
                    prospectList.add(newProspect)
                    val adapter = (prospectList)
                    recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(adapter)
                    recyclerView.itemAnimator = SlideInUpAnimator()

                }
            }
        }

        switchWaiting.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            isWaitingSelected = isChecked
            switchInProgress.isClickable = false
            switchValidate.isClickable = false

            if (isChecked) {
                // Filtrer la liste prospectList pour ne garder que les prospects en attente
                filteredList = prospectList.filter { prospect ->
                    prospect.status == "En attente"
                } as MutableList<Prospect>
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(filteredList as MutableList<Prospect>)
                if(filteredList.size == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@AdminProspects,
                        "Liste vide pour le moment",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } else {
                // Rétablir la liste complète prospectList
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(prospectList)
                switchInProgress.isClickable = true
                switchValidate.isClickable = true
            }

        }

        switchInProgress.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            isInProgressSelected = isChecked
            switchWaiting.isClickable = false
            switchValidate.isClickable = false

            if (isChecked) {
                // Filtrer la liste prospectList pour ne garder que les prospects en attente
                filteredList = prospectList.filter { prospect ->
                    prospect.status == "En progression"
                } as MutableList<Prospect>
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(filteredList as MutableList<Prospect>)
                if(filteredList.size == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@AdminProspects,
                        "Liste vide pour le moment",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } else {
                // Rétablir la liste complète prospectList
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(prospectList)
                switchWaiting.isClickable = true
                switchValidate.isClickable = true
            }
        }

        switchValidate.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            isValidatedSelected = isChecked
            switchWaiting.isClickable = false
            switchInProgress.isClickable = false
            if (isChecked) {
                // Filtrer la liste prospectList pour ne garder que les prospects en attente
                filteredList = prospectList.filter { prospect ->
                    prospect.status == "Validé"
                } as MutableList<Prospect>
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(filteredList as MutableList<Prospect>)
                if(filteredList.size == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@AdminProspects,
                        "Liste vide pour le moment",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } else {
                // Rétablir la liste complète prospectList
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(prospectList)
                switchWaiting.isClickable = true
                switchInProgress.isClickable = true
            }
        }

        switchPro.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isChecked ->
            switchPerso.isClickable = false
            if(isChecked){
                // Filtrer la liste prospectList pour ne garder que les prospects en attente
                filteredList = filteredList.filter { prospect ->
                    prospect.type == "Professionnel"
                } as MutableList<Prospect>
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(filteredList as MutableList<Prospect>)
                if(filteredList.size == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@AdminProspects,
                        "Liste vide pour le moment",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }else{
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(prospectList)
                switchPerso.isClickable = true
            }
        }

        switchPerso.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isChecked ->
            switchPro.isClickable = false
            if(isChecked){
                // Filtrer la liste prospectList pour ne garder que les prospects en attente
                filteredList = filteredList.filter { prospect ->
                    prospect.type == "Particulier"
                } as MutableList<Prospect>
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(filteredList as MutableList<Prospect>)
                if(filteredList.size == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@AdminProspects,
                        "Liste vide pour le moment",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }else{
                recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(prospectList)
                switchPro.isClickable = true
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(prospect: Prospect) {
        // Créez une intention pour lancer l'activité AdminProspectsDetails et transmettez les données du prospect
        val intent = Intent(this, AdminProspectsDetails::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("email", prospect.email)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


}
```

This is the adapter whitch is used to retrive my prospect data :

```html
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model.CardClickListener
import ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model.PROSPECT_ID_EXTRA
import ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model.Prospect
import ml2v.demenagement.all.android.ui.interfaces.AdminProspectsDetails
import ml2v.demenagement.app.android.R
import java.io.Serializable


class ProspectAdminAdapter(private val prospectList: MutableList<Prospect>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProspectAdminAdapter.ProspectAdminViewHolder>() {
    private var cardClickListener: CardClickListener? = null
    inner class ProspectAdminViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textProspectName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_card)
        val textEmail: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.email_card)
        val textPhone: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_card)
        val textMove: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.move_card)
        val textStatus: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_card)
        val buttonSendRequest: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.send_request_card)
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val position = adapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    val prospect = prospectList[position]
                    cardClickListener?.onClick(prospect)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProspectAdminViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cardview_prospects, parent, false)
        return ProspectAdminViewHolder(view)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProspectAdminViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val prospect = prospectList[position]
        holder.textEmail.text = "Adresse email : "+prospect.email
        holder.textProspectName.text = "Nom du prospect : "+prospect.nom
        holder.textPhone.text = "Téléphone : "+prospect.tel
        holder.textMove.text = "Type de prestation : "+prospect.type
        holder.textStatus.text = "Statut de la prestation : "+prospect.status

        holder.buttonSendRequest.setOnClickListener {
            val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            val db = Firebase.firestore
            val userId = currentUser.uid

            val prospectsCollection = db.collection("demenagement")

            prospectsCollection.whereEqualTo("mail", prospect.email).get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
                for (document in querySnapshot.documents) {
                    val documentRef = prospectsCollection.document(document.id)
                        documentRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener {
                            // Suppression réussie
                            val currentPosition = holder.bindingAdapterPosition
                            prospectList.removeAt(currentPosition)
                            notifyItemRemoved(currentPosition)
                        }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Log.d("TAG", "Message de débogage"+e)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return prospectList.size
    }

    fun setCardClickListener(listener: CardClickListener) {
        cardClickListener = listener
    }
}
```

My prospect class  :

```html
package ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model

var ProspectList = mutableListOf<Prospect>()
val PROSPECT_ID_EXTRA = "ProspectExtra"
data class Prospect(
    val categorie: String,
    var email: String,
    var nom: String,
    var siret: String,
    var tel: String,
    var type: String,
    var user: String,
    var status: String
)
```

the. card listener :

```html
package ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model

interface CardClickListener{
    fun onClick(prospect: Prospect)
}
```

and my propect detail :

```html
package ml2v.demenagement.all.android.ui.interfaces

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import ml2v.demenagement.all.android.data.model.Prospect
import ml2v.demenagement.app.android.R


class AdminProspectsDetails:ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_prospect_details)
        actionBar?.hide()


    }
}
```

I know the detail has not been insert but i would like just to verify if i can opened the card in my new activity. I probably doing something wrong but i don't know what...

Many thanks for helping

Comment: In your adapter you have declared the method to set the listener


`fun setCardClickListener(listener: CardClickListener) {
        cardClickListener = listener
}`


but you never call the method from the activity/fragment

Comment: So i have to call it from my adminprospect ? this already done but i don't know what i have to do... Do you have an exemple or something like ?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the adapter and click listener in this way

```
val adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(prospectList) // make this global
adapter.setCardClickListener(this)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

but every time you update your list you do something like this

```
val adapter = (prospectList)
recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(adapter)
```

In this way you are assigning a new adapter to the recycler view, not the first one defined, and you are losing your click listener.

Create the global var adapter and use it in this way

```
recyclerView.adapter = adapter // the global var
```

instead of

```
recyclerView.adapter = ProspectAdminAdapter(adapter)
```